# How to use 51 degrees library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to make websites for mobile users. I wanted to use 51 degrees library, however the documentation is not intuitive. Any help? I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: Do you have any specific question? This question will soon be closed if you dont ask something specific :)

Comment: What do you mean by "51 degrees library,?"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think if you have gone through [this link](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Foundation/InstallationInstructions.aspx?CATReferrer=5) which is having detailed instructions for using it. You will also need some mobile device emulator like Android SDK to create requests from mobile device easily.

This will get you started. Please add more details about your problem if you have any as @Shobhan said